# How to select all rows from column has different value "Select All or both"

Tags: php, mysql

I have in my table a column called grad_under in this column

```
graduate=0
undergraduate=1
```

Now I can select graduate only or undergraduate only if the user select both (all) how I can put the two value in one variable,so I can fetch both grad and undergrad?

```
<select name="gradunder" id="gradunder">

        <option value="1">Graduate</option>
        <option value="0">Undergraduate</option>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Both</option>
      </select>
```

This is the MySQL query that I'm using to fetch the rows. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$result2 ="SELECT * FROM  curriculumcourses  
    NATURAL JOIN courses  
    WHERE  semester_ava='$avalablesemster' 
    AND curriculum_id IN (
        SELECT curriculum_id 
        FROM curriculum 
        WHERE '".$coursneededdate."' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate and grad_under='".$gradunder."')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If selected choice is empty(Both) then skip your last `AND` part

```
$result2 ="SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  curriculumcourses NATURAL 
  JOIN courses 
WHERE semester_ava = '$avalablesemster' 
  AND curriculum_id IN 
  (SELECT 
    curriculum_id 
  FROM
    curriculum 
  WHERE '".$coursneededdate."'
   BETWEEN startdate  AND enddate ";
if(!empty($gradunder)){
 $result2 .=" AND grad_under = '".$gradunder."'";
}
 $result2 .=")";
```

Also its better to use `JOIN` instead of subquery

Comment: @HussainAlmalki that was a typo the last `$result` should be `$result2`

Comment: Many thanks this is working @m-khalid-junaid. Now I can select courses from different curriculums, but I have one problem that if two curriculum have the same course it will fetch them both. is there any way to avoid this deplucation?   if a course in both curriculum I need to fetch one of them only?

Comment: @HussainAlmalki i guess you should ask a new question with a detailed brief regarding your problem

Comment: I will try by myself first @m-khalid-junaid thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str='';
if($gradunder==''){
    $str=" ('1','0') ";
}
else{
    $str=" ('".$gradunder."') ";
}
$result2 ="SELECT * FROM  curriculumcourses  "
."NATURAL JOIN courses  "
."WHERE  semester_ava='$avalablesemster' " 
."AND curriculum_id IN ( "
."  SELECT curriculum_id "
."  FROM curriculum "
."  WHERE '".$coursneededdate."' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate and grad_under IN '".$str."')";
?>
```

Comment: By the way I think it is really good if you set value, but not empty string for "both" in case it is possible answer. At least it talks for a good style.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two values (grad or not) why not only concatenate  the " and grad_under = ..." To the query string if the value is not 'both'?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set gradunder as a value of 2, otherwise it won't get passed because it's blank. Then in your php you would need to check if the condition is 2, and then append the query based on that check.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_REQUEST['gradunder'] == ''){

$query = SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM curriculumcourses cu,courses c 

WHERE cu.curriculum_id = c.curriculum_id AND 

c.startdate<$coursneededdate AND 

c.enddate>$coursneededdate

}else{

SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM curriculumcourses cu,courses c WHERE 

cu.curriculum_id = c.curriculum_id AND

c.startdate<$coursneededdate AND 

c.enddate>$coursneededdate AND 

c.grad_under = $_REQUEST['gradunder'];

}
```